# Can't execute method rabbitMq

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

У меня есть BackgroundService который слушает Queue.

и отправляю в Queue сообшение :

```
{
  "Name": "ASD"
}
```

но когда я запускаю приложение вызывается метод StartAsync , но StartAsync не вызывает DoWork, и приложение заканчивает работу и удаляет сообшение с Queue.

**Как вызвать метод DoWork?**

```
 public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly IBulkImporterProcessWorker<BulkQueueModel> _worker;
        private readonly IMessageHandler<BulkQueueModel> _messageHandler;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private IEnumerable<IConsumer> _consumers;

        private readonly StepConfiguration _steps;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IBulkImporterProcessWorker<BulkQueueModel> worker, IMessageHandler<BulkQueueModel> messageHandler, IConfiguration configuration, IEnumerable<IConsumer> consumers)
        {
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            _worker = worker ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(worker));
            _messageHandler = messageHandler ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(messageHandler));
            _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
            _steps = configuration.GetSection("HandlerConfiguration").Get<StepConfiguration>();

            _consumers = consumers ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(consumers));
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var config = _configuration.GetSection("rabbitMq").Get<Bondx.RabbitMQ.Extentions.ConsumerConfiguration>();
            int numberOfConsumer = _configuration.GetValue<int>("numberOfConsumer");

            _consumers.SubscribeAsync<QueueMessage<BulkQueueModel>>(DoWork);

            _worker.Start(null, config, Bondx.RabbitMQ.Extentions.Factory.ConsumerType.Classic, numberOfConsumer, DoWork, _logger);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task DoWork(QueueMessage<BulkQueueModel> model, IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            await _messageHandler.ExecuteAsync(model.Message, _steps);
        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _worker.Stop();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

**Model**

```
    public class QueueModel
    {
        [DbParameter("id", 1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

**Program.CS**

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
               .ConfigureLogging((ctx, logging) =>
               {
                   logging.AddConfiguration(ctx.Configuration);
                   logging.AddConsole();
               })
               .UseNLog()
               .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
               {
                   services.AddProducer(hostContext.Configuration, "rabbitMq:Configuration");
                   services.AddBulkImporterHandler();
                   services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
               });
```

Answer (score 1):

вам нужно реализовать метод BackgroundService:

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
     while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
        ...
        await DoWork(...);
     }
    }
```

Comment: у меня он есть , я отредактировал вопрос можете посмотреть

Comment: DoWork() вызвать нужно (см. ответ)

Comment: все равно работает также как работал

Comment: нужна более подробная информация, добавьте полный код вашего worker-а и класса регистрации сервисов

Comment: добавил весь код

Comment: у вас проблема не с BackgroundService, а с правильным функционирование RabbitMQ. https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit/issues/363